# SQLAlchemy can't set unmapped properties

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to use unmapped properties in my SQLAlchemy model class.
This is simply what I'm doing:

```
class Event(db.Model):
    ....
    is_favourite = False
```

When I'm trying to set the value of this unmapped property I've got a strange behaviour. This is what happens (suppose I have a list of 3 events):

```
events[0].is_favourite = True
events[1].is_favourite = True
events[2].is_favourite = True
current_app.logger.info(events[0].is_favourite)
current_app.logger.info(events[1].is_favourite)
current_app.logger.info(events[2].is_favourite)
```

This prints:

> True False True

While I'm expecting

> True True True

This, to me, seems a very strange behaviour, considering this is just a class property.
Why is that happening?
Is there any way to use unmapped properties in SQLAlchemy?

**Edit**

As [stephen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/111033/stephen-fuhry) pointed out in the comment the correct way to achieve this is using the reconstructor.
By the way my problem was in the query itself is since I was iterating over

```
Event.query.filter(Event.uuid.in_(events_uuids))
```

instead of

```
Event.query.filter(Event.uuid.in_(events_uuids)).all()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you take SQLAlchemy out of the equation, you're generally confusing what should be an instance variable with a class definition variable. You'll probably end up with thread-safety issues too..

SQLAlchemy does some funky stuff under the hood with model objects. [This might point you in the right direction if you want to learn more](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/constructors.html#constructors-and-object-initialization)

What you probably want to do is this:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import reconstructor

class Event(db.Model):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.init_on_load()

    @reconstructor
    def init_on_load(self):
        self.is_favourite = False
```

Comment: This still not works. If I set it to True i got (same as in the question) I still got some False and some True without any reason.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the reconstructor (which i dind't know). By the way the problem was in my query since I iterate over :Event.query.filter(Event.uuid.in_(events_uuids)) instead of Event.query.filter(Event.uuid.in_(events_uuids)).all()